# how to Heighlight If space will come betweent text in Lucene heighlighting in Java

Tags: java, jsp, lucene

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.StringReader;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Fragmenter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleFragmenter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleHTMLFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream file = null;
        String result = "<html><body><div>(i) the recognised association shall have the approval of the Forward  Markets  Commission established under the Forward  Contracts (Regulation) Act, 1952 (74 of 1952) in respect of trading in derivatives and shall function in accordance with the guidelines or conditions laid down by the Forward  Markets  Commission; </div>  <body> </html>";

        try {

            TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("f", "Forward  Markets"));
            QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
            SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter(
                    "<span class=\"highlight\">", "</span>");
            org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter highlighter = new org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter(
                    formatter, scorer);
            Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleFragmenter(result.length());
            highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter);
            TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29)
                    .tokenStream("f",

                    new StringReader(result));
            String result1 = highlighter.getBestFragments(tokenStream, result,
                    1, "...");
            if (result1.length() == 0) {
                result1 = result;
            }
            String finalhtml = "<html>" + "<style>\n" + ".highlight{\n"
                    + " background: yellow;\n" + "}\n" + "</style>" + "<body>"
                    + result1 + "</body></html>";

            byte[] contentInBytes = finalhtml.getBytes();
            file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\myhtml.html"));
            file.write(contentInBytes);
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

This is My code when i set text  "recognised" or "association" its Highlighting Perfect But when i set text="Forward  Markets"  its noe Highlighting please tell me where am doing Mistake please help me how to Highlight text if space will come .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `recognised` and `association` are terms, but `forward markets` is not a term.  It's two terms, `forward` and `markets`, which should be found in sequence.  This is generally refered to as a "Phrase".  [`PhraseQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) can be used to find it, though generally the easier way is to just use a query parser, like:

```
StandardQueryParser parser = new StandardQueryParser(analyzer);
Query query = parse.parse("f:\"Forward Markets\"")
Query Scorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
//.......
```

If you do decide to manually construct your `PhraseQuery`, read the documentation carefully.  You must add each Term to the query individually, like:

```
phrasequery.add(new Term("f", "forward"));
phrasequery.add(new Term("f", "markets"));
```

On a similar note, when manually constructing queries, be mindful of your analyzer.  You query above includes capitalization.  Terms passed into a `TermQuery` manually are not analyzed.  If you are using an analyzer with a `LowercaseFilter` (`StandardAnalyzer`, for instance), this will lead to you finding no results.